# Trigonometric limits and algebraic limit

Tags: calculus, limits

Let $f(x) = \sin x$ , when $x \neq n\pi;$ and $2$, when $x=n\pi$ where $n \in \mathbb Z$,

$g(x) = x^2+1$, when $x\neq 2$ and equal to $~3$, when $x =2$ ,

then find $$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}~g(f(x))$$

Please guide how to proceed.

Comment: Please review my updates as the question was a mess of MathJax and make sure I got it correct. Regards

Comment: $$\lim_{x\to a}f(g(x)) = \lim_{x\to b} f(x)$$ where $$b = \lim_{x\to a} g(x)$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$g(f(x))=g(\sin x)=\sin^2x+1$

$\lim_{x\to0}(\sin^2x+1)=(\lim_{x\to0}\sin x)^2+1=0+1$

But $f(0)=2$ and $g(f(0))=g(2)=3$

Comment: I'm very impressed you understood the question.  I tried to typeset it and gave up.

Comment: Thanks ...a lot..to all of you...and especially lab bhattacharjee...